# WPF fade in animation disapears after finish

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created fade animation for my icon, but when animation finished the icons sets back to alpha 0. How can I get him to stay in 1?

```
var a = new DoubleAnimation
           {
               From = 0.0,
               To = 1.0,
               FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
               Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
           };
           var storyboard = new Storyboard();

           storyboard.Children.Add(a);
           Storyboard.SetTarget(a, IconGlass);
           Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
           storyboard.Begin();  

       }
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="IconGlass" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,39" Opacity="0">
```

Comment: What do you think `FillBehavior.Stop` mean?

Comment: Thanks, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this occurs because in your StackPanel you have the Property Opacity set to 0. What you are doing is,

1. You have a StackPanel with Opacity 0.
2. You add a Animation to your StackPanel to grow up the opacity.
3. But after finish the animation, StackPanel will have his default value of Opacity, that is 0.

its not the best way, but you can remove **Opacity="0"** and Add **Visibility="Collapsed"**

And when you animation start put your StackPanel Visible.

```
IconGlass.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

So when finishing the animation, will no desapear the StackPanel.

Know that this is not the best practise to do, but maybe one of the simplest or fastest way.

I hope this help. greetings!